# Codeblocks no input file compilation error with foreign characters

Tags: codeblocks

I just downloaded code blocks with mingw and whenever I create a new file and try to run it I get this error:

```
obj\Debug\main.o No such file or directory

error: no input files
```

Here is an image of the error:

[image]

When I installed the program I thought it wasn't working because mingw wasn't added to path but when I tried adding `C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW` and `C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin` to it, I got no results

The original directory I stored the project was named `C:\Users\gamin\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\Programming\Cpp\Alekos`.

I tried changing the directory to `C:\Alekos` which has no foreign characters and it worked so can someone tell me if I can do something to make it work in the original directory without renaming it?

Comment: Can it be the backslash `\`. If you use `/` as path separator instead it probably works. The problem is that in a string `\` + letter can be an escaped control character.

Comment: @JoopEggen Doesn't work. Do you have any other suggetions?

Comment: Special character rely on the actually used encoding (and not necessarily what you see: Windows, Windows command line, Linux. You can dump a directory listing into a file and check the encoding with Notepad++ or such